# Escaping a Linux path in Python without quotes, the correct way

Tags: python, shell, path, escaping

I'm seeing a large amount of answers on here to this question that are blatantly incorrect or are partially correct but don't account for any variances outside of a small scope.

here is my path:

```
"/home/user/text/Chapter 1-100"
```

In bash/zsh I can hit tab and have this path properly escaped, or I can use:

```
printf '%q' "/home/user/text/Chapter 1-100"
```

returns:

```
/home/user/text/Chapter\ 1-100
```

which is exactly what I need and I cannot compromise on this whatsoever, it must be escaped this way to be a compatible path for concatenating a few hundred files with ffmpeg in batches of 5. Ffmpeg only accepts this path style, it does NOT accept quoted strings, single quoted strings, double backslashes '\\' or 4 backslashes.

The problem is that I am unable to recreate this using python. `Shlex.quote` just quotes the string. Using:

```
replace(' ', r'\ ') or (' ', '\ ') or (' ', '\\ ') or (' ', '\\') or (' ', r'\\ ')
```

`os.normpath(path)` also isn't giving me a valid path. Most of these either leave the spaces untouched, or add TWO backslashes, I am baffled as to why it wont just allow me to have a single backslash. No matter what I try, I either get a space or I get two backslashes.

I need the literal Unix accepted, escaped path. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

More context:
I wrote a script that uses natsort to sort wav files in order (because they are audio books and need to be in order) then iterates over the list of the few hundred wav files and splits them into groups of 5 each and then appends that group to a file in a format that ffmpeg accepts ex:

> file path/to/the/file/Chapter\ 200/file.wav

So in the end I am left with Numbered text files 1-5.txt - 6-10.txt etc.. that can easily be used with ffmpeg to concat these files for later processing into mp4 files.

This issue pertains to the path needing to be properly escaped. ffmpeg isnt accepting anything besides the UNIX standard path expansion "\ " instead of " "

As asked here is the code:

```
#!/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import glob
import re
import ffmpeg
from rich import print
from natsort import natsorted
import shutil
import shlex


def natsorter(list, path):
    files = glob.glob(f"{path}/*.wav")
    files = natsorted(files)
    return files


# def sorted_alphanumeric(data):
# convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
# alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ]
# return sorted(data, key=alphanum_key)

# this is where I start sorting wav files
# add fils to a list, sort list and create a new list
# that are lists of 5 audio files ie 1-5, 6-10 etc...
newlist = []
path = os.getcwd()
files = glob.glob(f"{path}/*.wav")
# send list of files and path of files to sort them numerically in order
# this is important for an audiobook
newlist = natsorter(files, path)

# create empty slices array
slices = []


# function to slice an array into chunks of {n}
def divide_chunks(l, n):
    # Looping until length 1
    # start at 0 (first), to the full length, n is the step
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        # yield is like return it creates a list object and appends stuff to it
        yield l[i : i + n]
        slices.append(l[i : i + n])


# n is the number of files to slice together in ffmpeg file
# ie "file path/to/file.wav"
n = 5
x = list(divide_chunks(newlist, n))
print("--------------------")
print("SLICES YIELD: ")
print(x)
print("--------------------")


# create concat text files for ffmpeg
def concat_list():
    # files_concat = []
    i = 1
    total = 0
    for arrays in slices:
        total += len(arrays)
        name = f"{i}-{total}.txt"
        i += len(arrays)
        file = open(name, "w")
        for items in arrays:
            items = os.path.abspath(items).replace(" ", r"\ ")
            file.write("file " + items + "\n")
        file.close()
        # files_concat.append(name) -> switched to yield :) i learned a thing
        yield name


catfiles = list(concat_list())
# catfiles = []
print(catfiles)
for x in catfiles:
    ffmpeg.input(x, f="concat", safe=0).output(
        f"{x}.wav", codec="copy"
    ).overwrite_output().run()
    catfiles.append(f"{x}.wav")
```

Comment: You don't need to escape or quote paths if they're in python variables. Escaping is only needed in shell commands.

Comment: **Ffmpeg only accepts this path style, it does NOT accept quoted strings**. You're confused. Programs never see the quotes or escape sequences, they're parsed by the shell and the program receives its arguments without them. `ffmpeg` can't tell the difference between `'foo bar'` and `foo\ bar`.

Comment: When you run programs from Python you should use the `subprocess` module. You give it the arguments as a list, there's no shell processing and no need for quoting or escaping.

Comment: Yes thank you but thats not what Im talking about. Concatenating files with FFMPEG in the shell requires that they be in a text file in the format of 'file path/to/file\ with\ spaces.wav' on a new line for each concatenated file. So my question is still the same

Comment: But you don't need to use the shell. Use `subprocess.run()`.

Comment: Please show the code you're trying to run that you think requires the escape characters.

Comment: @Barmar I think the point is that the args given to `ffmpeg` will specify not the list of source filenames, but the path to a text file, which itself contains an appropriately formatted list of paths. But the example in the ffmpeg docs (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#Instructions) uses single-quoted paths. Although that example doesn't include anything with a space, so maybe spaces do create a problem.

Comment: @slothrop Thanks, now I understand. [This documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) explains the syntax in detail, but says that either single quotes or backslashes should work: **special characters and spaces must be escaped with backslash or single quotes.**

Comment: Yes it is causing me issues with single quotes and spaces for some reason, I added more context . Subprocess.run() isnt something I think that I would need in this situation, just a properly expanded UNIX path, which I would like to know how to do regardless

Comment: `os.path.abspath(items).replace(" ", r"\ ")` seems to do the intended when I run it and write the output to a file as in your script. This is on WSL with Ubuntu, I don't know if it can differ on other Linuxes. (Note, if you executed the same line at an interpreter prompt, the output would *appear* to have two backslashes, because the repr of a string escapes a backslash with a preceding backslash.)

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you. That must be the source of my confusion. It just appears as if its double backslashed. Like you both said, just using an f-string with single quotes was the answer to my main issue and this answers my other question. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write escape sequences. The documentation of [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) says:

> `file` *path*
> Path to a file to read; special characters and spaces must be escaped with backslash or single quotes.

So just put single quotes around the filename.

```
        for items in arrays:
            items = os.path.abspath(items)
            file.write(f"file '{items}'\n")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Im still curious about why there is no way to expand a path with spaces in a way that is compatible with UNIX and why replace() doesn't respect a backslash and a space. If anyone knows I would love to hear it still but I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: `shlex.quote()` *is* compatible with Unix. Quoting and escaping are both valid ways to deal with special characters. Your confusion is in thinking that the syntax of concat files is the same as shell syntax.

Comment: concat syntax is specific to ffmpeg, not a Unix thing.